# In Advance editor how to handling missing columns / column1 not found error in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

In Power Bi Most of the time I'm getting error column1 not found, if present day there is no data on database query.

How to handle it please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I'm handling this way., In advance editor alter the result line

**using data source**

```
results = if List.IsEmpty(Record. Field(List.First (Source[results]),"data")) 
               then Record. Field (List.First (Source[results]),"alterData") 
          else Record. Field((List.First (Source [results]), "data")
```

**user Power Bi static**

```
let
    Source = Json.Document (Web.Contents ("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                   [Headers=[zzzzz="xxxxxx"]])),
                   body = Source [body],
                   content = body[content],
                   #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList (content, Splitter.SplitByNothing(),
                     null,null, ExtraValues.Error}),
                  Tablel=Table. FromRecords ({
                                 [Columnl = ""]
                            }),
          result= if List.IsEmpty(content) then Tablel else #"Converted to Table"
in
    result
```